# On Change Getting Option Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a on change for my select statement, which I can access properties like `this.value` etc.

```
 $('select[name="ceremony"]').on('change', function(){
                    console.log( this )
    });
```

I need to somehow get the selected value text. None of the `this.options` stuff works

One I get it I want to display it like so:

```
$('.title').html( <here> )
```

Comment: `this.value` gets the selected value

Comment: $('.title').html($(this).find('option:selected').val())

Comment: `$(this).val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the selected option **text** (not *value*), you can use `$('option:selected',this).text()` :

```js
$('select').on('change',function(){
  console.log($('option:selected',this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>Test</option>
  <option>Test 2</option>
  <option>Test 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: var title = $('option:selected',this).text()
                            $('.ceremonyTitle').text(title)

Comment: it does not actually output, only to the console for some reason

Comment: @Victor Don't forget to change your selector `'select'`. In your case it will probably be `'select[name="ceremony"]'`

Answer (score 0):

`this.value` gets the current selected option

```js
 $('select[name="ceremony"]').on('change', function(){
                    $('.title').html(this.value)
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 class="title"></h1>

<select name="ceremony">
  <option>hi</option>  
  <option>there</option>

</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can find the selected option using the selector `:selected`
- Use the function `$.text` to get the visible text.
- Use the function `$.val` to get option's value.

```js
$('select').on('change',function(){
  var $selected = $(this).find(":selected");
  $('.title').html("Text: " + $selected.text() + ", Value: " + $selected.val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="1">Opt 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opt 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opt 3</option>
</select>
<h1 class="title">
</h1>
```